# Re-Render a React js functional component, SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

i have a simple question about re-rendering a functional react js component without re-rendering the whole page.

in several posts a saw people talking about:

---

LIBRARY: REACT-ROUTER-DOM

```
history.push("/");
history.goBack();
```

---

and this actually works, it re-renders my component and the useEffect hook in charge of loading the data in my DOM is working fine, but after two re-renders i got an error in my console:

---

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

---

This is a problem with the way the history.push() and the history.goBack(), because when i delete them there is no error.

This error comes from a action preformed in an unmounted component, so my question is.

How can i re-render a component so my initial useEffect hook can fetch the needed data?

---

HERE IS A PART OF MY CODE.

this is the useEffect that triggers when the component mounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getCategorias = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest('http://localhost:5000/api/admin/categorias/')
        setCategoriasData(responseData.categoriasActivas)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    getCategorias()

  }, [sendRequest])
```

And this is the 'POST' action, when the history.push() and the history.goBack() re-renders the component and the new data is shown because of the useEffect HOOK.

```
try {
        setEnviando(true)
        await sendRequest(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/admin/categorias",
          "POST",
          JSON.stringify({
            nombre: categoriaNueva,
            color: color,
          }),
          {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          }
        )
        message.success("Categoria creada exitosamente.")
        

        history.push("/dashboard/");
        history.goBack()
        
      } catch (err) {
        setEnviando(false)
        let error = err.toString()
        message.error(error)
        setColor("")
        setCategoriaNueva("")
      }
    }
```

As i said before everything is working quite well, i just have a problem with the re-render part.
If anybody can help me out i'll appreciate it, if not, maybe some documentation to guide me would be nice...

```
thank you very much
```

Comment: `history.push("/");
history.goBack();` Why do you need both at the same time?

Comment: @PrateekThapa i wanted to trigger the useEffect hook so my DOM get the lastest data fetched, and with the bottom answer i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to re-render a component is to update it's state. So what you can do is, simply add some state to the component and update it when you want to trigger a re-render as follows:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
...
const [updateFlag, setUpdateFlag] = useState(0);
    try {
        setEnviando(true)
        await sendRequest(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/admin/categorias",
          "POST",
          JSON.stringify({
            nombre: categoriaNueva,
            color: color,
          }),
          {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          }
        )
        message.success("Categoria creada exitosamente.")
        

        setUpdateFlag(updateFlag++);
        
      } catch (err) {
        setEnviando(false)
        let error = err.toString()
        message.error(error)
        setColor("")
        setCategoriaNueva("")
      }
    }
...
...
}
```

Notice the `setUpdateFlag(updateFlag++)` statement. That is the statement that would trigger a re-render.